# How can I remove filters from a RANKX function in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've been struggling with removing filters from the rank calculation in dax.

I have a sample table with units per store for individual items broken out by their respective Department, Category, Sub-Category, Parent Company, and Parent Brand.

```
testrank = RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Sales), CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[UnitsPerStore])),,ASC)
```

[image: Units Per Store with Rank]

As you can see from the above, the rank is working how I would expect. However, I want the end user to be able to filter to a particular brand they are curious about without affecting the rank. Below I filtered to ParentBrand of Carvet. The rank automatically changed based on the visual:

[image: Carvel filtered]

So the only filters that the end user applies that I want to affect the calculation are Department, Category, and Subcategory. So if someone looks up a particular UPC for example, they would see the rank of that upc based on the selection of the department/category/subcategory.

I tried using ALLEXCEPT within the function but got the wrong ranking:

```
Rank(allexcept) = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(Sales, Sales[CorporateDepartment], Sales[Category], Sales[SubCategory]), CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[UnitsPerStore])),,ASC)
```

[image: Rank with ALLEXCEPT]

Answer (score 0):

**Method1:**
Use New column:
`Rank = RANKX(Sales, Sales[UnitsPerStore],,ASC,Dense)`

**Method2:**
Use New measure:
`Rank = RANKX(ALL(Sales), CALCULATE(MAX(Sales[UnitsPerStore])),, ASC,Dense)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we are close on method 2 and 3. In both cases when I filter on parent brand for instance, the rank remains the same from the selection I made in Category (which is what I want). However it seems the ranks are repeating, almost like it has a group by applied to it:

```
method2 = RANKX(FILTER(ALL(Sales), Sales[CorporateDepartment] = max(Sales[CorporateDepartment]) && Sales[Category] = max(Sales[Category]) && Sales[SubCategory]=max(Sales[SubCategory])), CALCULATE(MAX(Sales[UnitsPerStore])),, ASC,Dense)


method3 = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(Sales, Sales[CorporateDepartment], Sales[Category], Sales[SubCategory]), CALCULATE(Sum(Sales[UnitsPerStore])),,ASC,Dense)
```

[Method 2 and 3 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyYNb.png)